# Are there are other known functions that give the same set of zeros as the Riemann zeta function inside the critical strip besides $\eta(s)$?

Tags: riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series

The zeros of the Dirichlet's eta function $\eta(s)$ inside the critical strip match the non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$, as $\eta(s) = (1 - 2^{1-s}) \zeta(s)$.

What are the other known functions that give the same set of zeros of $\zeta(s)$ inside the critical strip?

**EDIT**:

I'm interested in functions given explicitly in series form:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} f(n) \, n^{-s}$$

Comment: $\zeta(s)e^{f(s)}$ for any entire function $f(s)$ gives a very large set of examples....

Comment: Surely you can construct arbitrarily many such functions. Just multiply $\zeta$ with some other function.

Comment: Perhaps I have to rephrase it, I'm interested in other functions given explicitly in series summation form, does that makes sense? Like in: "are there are other series that give the same zeros of..."

Comment: @GregMartin: I understand that multiplying a series by some function does not immediately gives a series in the form of my edit, specially if the series is not absolutely converging in the region of interest (the critical strip), please let me know if your comment still holds with this edit, thanks.

Comment: There are also still lots of Dirichlet series (that's the name for series of the type you want) with the same zeros, because there are lots of Dirichlet series $g(s)$ with no zeros in the critical strip, and therefore $\zeta(s)g(s)$ will be an example (the product of two Dirichlet series is again a Dirichlet series). For example, any finite product of functions of the form $1-wm^{-s}$, where $m\ge2$ is an integer and $w$ is a complex number with $|w|\le 1$, is a (finite) Dirichlet series with no zeros in the critical strip.

Comment: @GregMartin: that's the exactly the answer I've been looking for, a class of Dirichlet series (by products of Dirichlet series is obviously acceptable, as I read on Hardy's book) that satisfy the zeros condition I stated! Will accept it as answer if you'd like to post it, thanks!

Comment: One example is the Dirichlet lambda function $\lambda (s)=\left(1-2^{-s}\right) \zeta(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2 n-1)^s}$.

Comment: @GregMartin, hi, going through it I notice I don't get the condition for complex $|w|$, shouldn't this condition be $|w| \ge 1$ instead of $|w| \le 1$, as for $\eta(s)$ we have $w=2$? thanks